# Iterating rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, iteration

I want to first iterate through the item number and then for a particular item, I need to iterate through the week number. Main aim is to flag the week number of a each item in which there is inventory addition. I am newbie, so I am not aware of how to do double iteration.
[image: Data]

[image: Output will look like this]

Output will be like this. The flag becomes one when the inventory for the current week is greater than the previous one.

Comment: do you need a `for` loop inside a `for` loop?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give us anything .....

Comment: Are you using pandas? Or is that a list of lists

Comment: How is your data imported? Please note that an image is not as helpful as the real Text structure combined with the code snippet you usw for importing to understand what your situation is

Comment: @Jaxi ! Yeap! For loop inside a for loop is what I am looking for. But first for loop should iterate over distinct items instead of rows

Comment: Show us your code so far. Is this in pandas? numpy? a list of lists? We simply need more detail and then we can help you.

Comment: @SKSingh if you can give us how your data is presented, we can help you

Comment: @Attersson I am using Pandas data frame and  data is imported from a csv file using pandas

Comment: Your task description sounds like a good job for pandas - not for manually double iterating around....

Comment: OK, pd.dataframe then, perfect. Then show us the output oft df.head()

Comment: @SpghttCd I have edited the original question with the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC: You can try using `.groupby` item number followed by `.shift` in `dataframe` as following.

Suppose the original dataframe is as below:

```
   DIV_NBR  itm_nbr  WEEK_NO  DISTINCT_ITM_CNT  INVENTORY_IN_HAND
0       18    65874   201511               5.0             2925.0
1       18    65874   201512               5.0             2910.0
2       18    65874   201513               5.0             2961.0
3       19    65875   201511               5.0             2965.0
4       19    65875   201512               5.0             2971.0
```

Then:

```
# keep record of last week by grouping by item number and then using shift
df['LAST_WEEK'] = df.groupby('itm_nbr')['INVENTORY_IN_HAND'].shift()

# check if current inventory is greater than last week
df['Flag'] = (df['INVENTORY_IN_HAND'] - df['LAST_WEEK'])>0

# delete additional column
del df['LAST_WEEK']

# change flag int
df['Flag'] = df['Flag'].astype(int)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   DIV_NBR  itm_nbr  WEEK_NO  DISTINCT_ITM_CNT  INVENTORY_IN_HAND  Flag
0       18    65874   201511               5.0             2925.0     0
1       18    65874   201512               5.0             2910.0     0
2       18    65874   201513               5.0             2961.0     1
3       19    65875   201511               5.0             2965.0     0
4       19    65875   201512               5.0             2971.0     1
```

Comment: This is more or less exactly the way I'd describe, too. But imho instead of shift() and manually substracting just using diff() which does the same would be even more straight forward here.

Comment: I am not sure but I think someone may come up with efficient way of doing it.